# Html5 canvas and javascript document.getElementById() returns null

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to use html5 canvas and when I do

```
    var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

and here is the html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="512" height="480" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have no clue what's wrong

Comment: canvas hasn't loaded till the time you make the first call. try calling it on window load or document ready

Comment: @FelixKling That's a great post (good work!), wasn't aware of it, defiantly bookmark for later.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are your script is run before your DOM is ready and window has loaded, try for instance:

```
window.onLoad=function(){
    var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert your script before the closing body tag.

Like:

```
...
    <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

May you try to get it before DOM was loaded? Try to call your code inside this block:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
};
```

Comment: You posted a similar answer to the one I did, only ~ 3 minutes later. What advantage do you think your answer has over mine that you chose to add it?

Comment: sorry, didn't see that your have already posted correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `DOM Element` through `javascript`, make sure your java script code should triggered after DOM is loaded, use `document.onload` or `window.onload` callbacks to trigger your javascript code..

Enjoy Coding..